# Using Powershell, how do I eject an ISO image from a Hyper-V virtual machine?

Tags: hyper-v, powershell

I'm using the [Hyper-V module for PowerShell](http://pshyperv.codeplex.com/), and I've successfully mounted an ISO file onto a virtual machine. Question is: how do I eject (or unmount) it?

I'd prefer to use the PSHyperV stuff, if there's a solution. Failing that, dipping into WMI from PowerShell would be acceptable.

(Using Windows 2008 R2, if it makes a difference)

Answer (score 1):

```
Set-VMDisk
```

[HERE](http://pshyperv.codeplex.com/releases/view/21642#DownloadId=56216)'s a Powershell Hyper-V commandlet reference guide for future use.

Comment: A little more? I'm aware of Set-VMDisk. What's the magic incantation to get it to eject the ISO?

Comment: seriously dude the full usage is detailed in the linked document, there's loads of options, no way for any of us to just tell you what you need, you've not provided enough information.

Comment: I want to *unmount* an ISO file. What part of that is not clear? The documentation shows how to *mount* one, which I can already do.

Answer (score 1):

From the virtual machine I found that using Powershell did it for me:

mountvol DRIVELETTER: /d